# Mid Range RFID Reader and Vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, rfid

I've managed to create a simple application in VS2010 using vb.net to received data from COM2.

My RFID reader is connected via RS232. When my reader detected my Passive or Active RFID tag the data received my appliation is only "?".

Do i need to convert the data of the tag?

Here is the code i got so far.

```
Imports System.IO.Ports

Class MainWindow

Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    Label1.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
    Label2.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
    TextBox1.Text = com1.PortName
    TextBox2.Text = com1.BaudRate

    Button1.IsEnabled = False
    Try

        With com1
            .DtrEnable = True
            .RtsEnable = True
            .Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.None
            AddHandler .DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedHandler
        End With
        com1.Open()

        If com1.IsOpen = True Then
            Label1.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Shared Sub DataReceivedHandler(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    Dim sp As SerialPort = CType(sender, SerialPort)
    Dim indata As String = sp.ReadExisting()
    MessageBox.Show(indata)
End Sub
```

Comment: The manufacturer is the only one who can answer this question (in form of a documentation).

Comment: It is highly likely that any RFID data your device would read is encrypted.  To decrypt the data you would need the key which a manufacturer would only give to a authorized contractor/developer.  Then, like @mrgx has said, you would need the API documentation from the manufacturer.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your replies! I has the demo program and it can identify the tag id of of rfid tag(passive/active) but in my example application the data that i received is only "?". I can provide the id's of the tag if you want.